# Is this sentence "There are highly-compact places such as inside a vehicle" grammatically acceptable?

Tags: nouns

Or do I have to say "There are highly-compact places such as the inside of a vehicle"?

Can "inside a vehicle" together be regarded as a noun? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Both options, the one in the title, and the one in the body, are grammatically acceptable, though I would have a preference for eliminating the mis-match in number between the plural "highly-compact places" and the singular "inside a vehicle". If the subject is plural, I want the whole sentence to be plural, so "There are highly-compact places such as the insides of vehicles."

Yes, "inside a vehicle" is a noun phrase, referring to one of several places contained within a vehicle (for example the boot / trunk, passenger cabin, glove / map box, &c.). It's just another expression of "the interior".

Comment: _Inside a vehicle_ is not a noun and therefore can't be either singular or plural. To the extent the first one is acceptable (I would mark it `??` at best), it is being heard as _(the space (that is)) inside a vehicle_. In other words, it's pretending to be a noun phrase with a relative clause, but it's been cut down to just a prepositional phrase by Whiz-deletion (_that is_) and reference to earlier _places_. It doesn't need to be plural if it's ***the** place*, as an example.

Comment: ... Yes, the correctness of the labelling of prepositional phrases forced into service as subjects and objects (if they truly are) as 'noun phrases' depends on what definition of 'noun phrases' one accepts. [In the fridge is a good place to keep the milk. etc.] I like 'pretending to be a noun phrase'.